# Best way to automate the copy of two large files?

Tags: backup, dbf

There are two large (5 GB each) DBF files that need to be backed up before a process is run via MS Access. This is in case something gets corrupted.

Right now I am doing two filecopy() commands within the VBA but I suspect it is slow.

What is the best way to perform this backup automatically and efficiently? Can it be done from a batch file or something similar? I cannot install new software.

Comment: What is leading you to suspect it is slow?  Have you compared the speed to some other method of copying the same files (like from Explorer or a command prompt)?

Comment: @GuitarPicker Seems slower than manually selecting both files and pasting copies into the same folder at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a batch file here's what you can do:

```
COPY FILE.DBF B:\Backups
COPY FILE1.DBF B:\Backups
```

Another way to do it is using the command `Esentutl` (Windows Vista+)

```
ESENTUTL /y FILE.DBF /d B:\Backups\FILE.DBF
ESENTUTL /y FILE1.DBF /d B:\Backups\FILE1.DBF
```

Comment: Do I need quotes around the paths? Do they have to be in the same directory? Can I do COPY H:\Path\FILE.DBF H:\Path\FILEBACK.dbf ?

Comment: Quotes: Only if using a path with a space. Same Directory: Nope. COPY H:\Path\FILE.DBF H:\Path\FILEBACK.dbf yes.

Comment: also try esentutl, it's available in every version of windows, AND shows a percentage

Comment: Is it faster than COPY? What is /y and /d?

Comment: Is it faster than COPY? Possibly, mostly the same speed, but shows you where the transfer is at. What is /y and /d? /y=Copy  /d=destination filename

Comment: I just tried it and it says "invalid code"

Comment: It almost looks like this doesn't even support copy. It shows modes of operation: defrag /d, recovery /r, integrity /g, checksum /k, repair /p, file dump /m

Comment: see: http://i.imgur.com/lBxK9pa.png additionally, what version of windows are you using?

Comment: Windows Server 2003 R2

Comment: use the copy command